# Trying to get the first element of JSON array Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to implement a stock API. I have a JSON example:

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "DAI.DEX",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2022-04-05",
    "4. Output Size": "Full size",
    "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2022-04-05": {
        "1. open": "64.4900",
        "2. high": "64.8200",
        "3. low": "62.6200",
        "4. close": "62.9600",
        "5. volume": "3425810"
    },
    "2022-04-04": {
        "1. open": "63.9900",
        "2. high": "64.5400",
        "3. low": "62.8100",
        "4. close": "64.2600",
        "5. volume": "2538008"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to display the latest price so I always need the first element in Time Series Daily. In this example 2022-04-05. The list goes on for 20 years. I tried this:

```
var latestClose: String {
    timeSeriesDaily.first?.value.close ?? ""
}
```

But every time I rerun the app it displays different values and not constantly the first value.

Here my Code:

```
struct StockData: Codable {

     var metaData: MetaData
     var timeSeriesDaily: [String: TimeSeriesDaily]

     var latestClose: String {
         timeSeriesDaily.first?.value.close ?? ""
     }

     private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case metaData = "Meta Data"
         case timeSeriesDaily = "Time Series (Daily)"
     }

     struct MetaData: Codable {
         let information: String
         let symbol: String
         let lastRefreshed: String
         let outputSize: String
         let timeZone: String
    
         private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
             case information = "1. Information"
             case symbol = "2. Symbol"
             case lastRefreshed = "3. Last Refreshed"
             case outputSize = "4. Output Size"
             case timeZone = "5. Time Zone"
         }
     }

     struct TimeSeriesDaily: Codable {
         var open: String
         var high: String
         var low: String
         var close: String
         var volume: String
    
         private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
             case open = "1. open"
             case high = "2. high"
             case low = "3. low"
             case close = "4. close"
             case volume = "5. volume"
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Check your api response, if it is giving same type of response every time or it is changing its indexes every time you hit the api.

Comment: _The list goes on for 20 years_, I would check the documentation for the API to see if there is a way to download less data if all you need is the latest price. Either by passing some other parameters or using another endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no **first** element because the object is a dictionary which is unordered by definition.

To get the most recent item you have to get the dictionary `keys` (this returns an array) and sort them descending. The most recent date is the first item.

```
 var latestClose: String {
     guard let mostRecentDate = timeSeriesDaily.keys.sorted(by: >).first else { return "" }
     return timeSeriesDaily[mostRecentDate]!.close
 }
```